# How to compare two visible cells after putting autofilter in first row

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Dim F11, F22, Month, Year As Variant
      Dim f_name1, f_name2
      Dim wb1, wb2, wb3, wb4 As Workbook
      Dim sht1, sht2, sht3, sht4 As Worksheet
      Dim Total_DCR As Long
      Dim StartDate, EndDate As Date

    'Select Product Backlog File
     F11 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Product Backlog file (*.xlsm*), *.xlsm*")
      If (F11 <> vbNullString) Then
        If (F11 <> "False") Then
          f_name1 = F11
        End If
      End If
      If (f_name1 = "") Then
        MsgBox "The Product Backlog file must be specified."
        Exit Sub
      End If

    Set wb1 = Excel.Workbooks.Open(f_name1)
    Set sht1 = wb1.Sheets("Product Backlog")


    Set wb3 = ThisWorkbook
    Set sht3 = wb3.Sheets("check")
    With sht3

            StartDate = sht3.Range("J3").Value
            'Debug.Print StartDate

            If IsDate(StartDate) = True Then
            MsgBox ("The following string is a valid date expression")
            Else
            'if its not a date expression show a message box
            MsgBox ("The following string is not a valid date expression")
            End If

            EndDate = sht3.Range("J4").Value
            'Debug.Print EndDate

    End With

    wb1.Activate
    sht1.Activate
        sht1.Columns("O:O").Select
        wb1.Worksheets("Product Backlog").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        wb1.Worksheets("Product Backlog").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
            "O1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
            xlSortNormal

    With wb1.Worksheets("Product Backlog").Sort
            .SetRange Range("O1:O3437")
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply

    End With


    sht1.Range("$A$1:$X$3432").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:= _
            ">=" & CDbl(StartDate), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(EndDate)

    With sht1
        Total_DCR = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(102, 
        ActiveSheet.Range("O1:O5000").Columns(1))
        Debug.Print Total_DCR
    End With
     Dim rng As Range, rngVisible As Range, rngRow As Range, delay_count As Double
        Set rng = Range("$A$1:$X$5000")
        '// Get visible cells excluding header

   With rng
   Set rngVisible = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 
   End With 

   '// Must use "Cells" when dealing with "Rows" property 
   For Each rngRow In rngVisible.Rows 
   delay_count = delay_count + IIf(rngRow.Cells(1, "O") > rngRow.Cells(1, "X"), 1, 0) 
   Next MsgBox ("total delay DCR is" & delay_count)

   End Sub
```

The Product Backlog file work book contains random date from year 2017 to 2020 as per every month in Col O(actual date). same way Col X (required date)contains date as well. I am filtering Col O and col x based on the start date and end date entered in check sheet's J3,J4 column.The code must filter them for February 2020 dates and then compare between O and X dates. start date:01-02-2020 end date:29-02-2020

All the A1-X1 columns have filter dropdown added. when autofilter is applied it will filter the february 2020 dates only. A1-X1 row is there in first row with headers.

After autofilter the start date and end date in Col O I want to compare the visible Col O date cells with col x date for greater than logic.

Unable to find what is wrong in my code. anyone pls help.

The delay count comes here as 0. I am struck. please help.

Comment: You should start by reading http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2012/10/declaring-multiple-variables-with-one-dim-statement/ about how to declare your variables

Comment: Have you checked using the debugger if **a)** `rngVisible.Rows` returns the rows that should be visible **b)** the content of the cells `rngRow.Cells(1, "O")` and `rngRow.Cells(1, "X")` are what you expect?

Comment: @FunThomas checked rngVisible.Rows.count. It is 4999 as my selected range is("$A$1:$X$5000").help me to understand how I should proceed. The Total_DCR variable is nothing but the filtered rows for February 2020 month i.e it comes to 79 which is correct. but with in this visible 79 rows I want to check for the greater than condition between Col O and Col. X date. I have tried many ways but the delay count is 0 in the end. If I put FOR loop from 2 to Total_DCR  it is not working because it is taking the non visible cells  as well. The delay count should be 53.

Comment: @FunThomas need your help. Please guide me to proceed